# How do I access the values in the JSON model in my Dialogue list?

Tags: sapui5

I have retrieved a JSON model from an ajax call in UI5 but I can't access its members. I have seen examples of people doing something similar but it isn't working for me. Here is my code:

```
onSumbmitFlowGAkQ: function () {
            var oParameters = {
                "value": this.getView().byId("flowInputGAK").getValue()
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: "private url",
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(oParameters),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(data), "guidedAssistanceGAK");
                    this.setUpDialog();
                }.bind(this),
                error: function (e) {
                    MessageToast.show(e.status);
                }
            });

setUpDialog: function () {
            var lst = new List({
                items: {
                    path: "guidedAssistanceGAK>/flow",
                    template: new StandardListItem({
                        title: "{guidedAssistanceGAK>value}",
                        counter: "{guidedAssistanceGAK>ID}"
                    })
                }
            });
            var dialog = new Dialog({
                title: "choose one",
                content: lst,
                beginButton: new Button({
                    text: "OK",
                    press: function () {
                        dialog.close();
                    }
                }),
                afterClose: function () {
                    dialog.destroy();
                }
            });
            dialog.open();
            //this.oEditor.oRichTextEditor.setValue(this.getView().getModel("guidedAssistanceGAK").getProperty("/flow"));
        },
```

I am using the syntax "guidedAssistanceGAK>/flow" to access the data but it isn't working. I think this is a binding error. I was wondering what would be the right way to do this.

Comment: I recommend to use the UI5 framework with MVC. so dont create your view controls inside of the controller.
for more help I need some more information, maybe an online demo. at least the json

one additional thing I saw is that you do your setmodel on this.getView(). but your dialog fragment is another new view. try to first create the dialog and set the model into this new view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new dialog doesn't look to be part of the view, which is where your model lives. You could either do `this.getView().addDependent(dialog)`, or you could attach the model to the dialog with `dialog.setModel`.